# How to set StatusCode on Test.setMock

Tags: apex, httprequest, httpcalloutmock

I have a simple class that just calls the generic HTTPCallOUt method for its test class.

I want it to be able to fail in order to catch all the code. Here is my code:

```
    Test.startTest(); 
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new ExampleCalloutMock()); // I want this to be able to 
    fail in order to catch all the code in ClassCall 
    ClassCall.Method(recordId);
    test.stopTest();
```

Right now it always returns Code 200 and passes the test. I want it to return anything other than code 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do is dependency inject the desired static code into the mock's constructor

```
Test.startTest(); 
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new ExampleCalloutMock(400)); // <= inject desired status code  
ClassCall.Method(recordId);
test.stopTest();
```

**The mock callout**

```
public class ExampleCalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
  Integer statusCode;
  ExampleCalloutMock(Integer statusCode) {this.statusCode = statusCode;}

  public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
    
    
    // Create a fake response
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setBody('{"example":"test"}');
    res.setStatusCode(this.statusCode);  // use injected status code as response
    return res;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @cropredy in your answer do I need to create a new Class with the HTTP response?

Comment: see the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm) -- the mock callout class can be a top level class, or, in most cases, can be an inner class inside your test class